# Unique combinations of vector elements that fulfill criteria

Tags: r

I have a vector of integers, e.g., `totalVector <- c(4,2,1)`, and two variables `totalResult` and `totalNumber`. What I want to do is the following:

I want to to find all UNIQUE combinations of "totalNumber" elements from totalVector that add up to "totalResult". To clarify, if totalResult = 100 and totalNumber = 50, I want all combinations of 50 elements from totalVector that have a sum of 100 (repetitions are obviously allowed, but duplicate results such as 25 fours and 25 re-arranged fours should only be counted once).

I originally did this by expanding the total vector (repeating each element 50 times), getting all combinations of 50 elements with `combn()` and then filtering their sums. For large values however, this proved very inefficient, and failed due to the sheer amount of data. Is there a quicker and less data-heavy way to do this?

Comment: You should ask a mathematician for an algorithm other than brute force.

Comment: You are essentially trying to find the positive solutions to a system of two linear Diophantine equations (one equation involving `totalResult` and one involving `totalNumber`). [Ehrhart polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial) are relevant for simply counting the number of solutions, though there might be another approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is looking for the combinations with repetition of a vector that sum to a particular number. This will do it:

```
totalVector <- c(4,2,1)
totalNumber <- 50
totalResult <- 100

library(RcppAlgos)
myAns <- comboGeneral(totalVector, totalNumber, repetition = TRUE,
                      constraintFun = "sum", comparisonFun = "==",
                      limitConstraints = totalResult)

dim(myAns)
[1] 17 50

all(apply(myAns, 1, sum) == totalResult)
[1] TRUE
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `RcppAlgos`

Comment: Nice answer (+1), but how long before it becomes computationally infeasible? It still seems like a brute-force approach (albeit one aided by a well-written package).

Comment: @JohnColeman, first of all I am a huge fan. I have learned so much from your  contributions. Secondly, you are right (as usual)... this will become computationally infeasible quickly. This very problem has aided me to sleep many many many nights (I know the general saying is "kept me up", but I find comfort in these types of problems). So far, my conclusion is that you can't do better than an optimized brute force for the general case. I have tried (and failed) to apply an integer partition approach. My current approach is to apply a sort of binary approach.. continued

Comment: @JohnColeman, as we are able to generate the _`nth`_ combination, we can test the `sum` (or whatever constraint function we are applying) and apply loose bounds on where we should be searching. This will (in theory) at least limit the space of results we are testing (albeit in a brute forceish manner). Addendum to the last comment: I should have said that " my current research" instead of "my current approach".. meaning that this is under active development.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you what you need for a small sample, but you will encounter issues with combinatorial explosion very quickly as you increase the size of the problem

```
tv <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
tn <- 5
tr <- 20
combinations <- combn(tv, tn)
equals.tr <- apply(combinations, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) sum(x) == tr)
combinations[, equals.tr]
```